# Why do *some* DATETIME fields in my database corrupt like this? (MySQL/MSACCESS)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, ms-access

[image: Example of corruption inside of table]

Oddly enough, when I click on one of the fields the correct date and time will appear, but revert to it's previous state (###########) once I click away.

Does any body know what could be causing this?  I believe one of the queries is corrupting the DATETIME fields in this program.  A query randomly broke earlier when it was appending information into a table, and clearing the table solved the problem.

Comment: Very beginner's question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lol, widen the column display a little bit and then see :) Thats just because the display field is not wide enough. Its nothing related to the data storage itself. Applies to excel as well. Such a common thing.

Comment: Its so ironic that the answer you expect to get most down-votes on actually keeps getting up-votes

Comment: Hey, thanks!  Yeah, I feel like a complete idiot; but honestly I'd been trying to figure it out for so long I don't even care.